# Input file checking using getline an >> operator in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, input, getline

I have written a code here which reads a input file line by line and creates a vector of vectors which I then use as a matrix, later on, in my homework. This is the code:

```
vector<vector<int>> inputMatrix;
string line;
while(!file.eof())
{
    getline(file, line);
    stringstream ss(line);

    int num;
    vector<int> temp;

    while(ss >> num)
    {
        temp.push_back(num);        
    }
    inputMatrix.push_back(temp);
}
```

However, some input files may contain non-integer values. I would like to integrate a input check feature for the matrix creation so that when there is a non-integer value in the input file, my program would quit.

How can I achieve this? Would it be possiple to write somewhere in this while loop or somewhere else in the code?

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to integrate a input check feature for the matrix creation so that when there is a non-integer value in the input file, my program would quit.

The `stringstream` already does this check for you. You can simply test its state after the while loop. If it failed to parse a non integer value, the failbit will be set to true.

Here's a [working demo](http://ideone.com/uqFbsJ) (with some small improvements):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> inputMatrix;
    string line;
    while(getline(cin, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);

        int num;
        vector<int> temp;

        while(iss >> num)
        {
            temp.push_back(num);        
        }
        if(!iss) {
            cout << "Bad input detected!" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        inputMatrix.push_back(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
12 13 46 3
42 2.6 5
```

Output

```
Bad input detected!
```

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If
>   extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in
>   value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min()
>   is written and failbit flag is set.

So you could simply add an if clause after your while loop:

```
while (ss >> num)
{
  temp.push_back(num);
}
if (ss.fail()) // explicitly check for failbit
{
  expected_integer_error();
}
```

Comment: `if(!ss) { ...`should suffice.